# Preserving changed fill color after INDEX and MATCH lookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, calc

Good evening.

I'm having a hard time trying to find my issue over Google for several hours already but I guess it's being hard to explain what I'm trying to find. Anyways...

I have a list of serial numbers from an inventory and I already added functions and conditional formatting to search for an inputted value over the whole column of serial numbers. My problem is, I want to automate the process highlighting the matched value and keeping it highlighted for better visualization purposes. My spreadsheet already searched the value over the inventory, returns me the row number where the matched value is located and the description of the item found, however, I want the item in the inventory to get highlighted and stay highlighted.

I had a similar result with conditional formatting, however, after I search the next serial number, the style vanished from the previous cell and goes to the next matched item. Instead, I wanted it to remain with its previous fill color.

Any help with VBA or conditional formatting will be appreciated.

My functions for looking up data and so on are...

To find the row line where the serial was matched:
`=MATCH(H2;F:F;0)`

To get the description of the item found:
`=INDEX(D:D;MATCH(H2;F:F;0))`

To catch if the item was found or not in the inventory:
`=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(H2;F:F;0);"FOUND !");"NOT FOUND !")`

Comment: Sounds quite complex - would it be possible to create a minimal example with sample data?

Answer (score 0):

Conditional formating will not work since it would only capture the current search item. You will need VBA code to achieve what you want. CHeck the following code (and make the appropriate changes).

it Sould be placed inside the Sheet object in VBA project navigator. Every time you update a cell, it will check if the cell that changed is the one where you search for an item. If so, it will go to the indicated row and change that cell background color to yellow.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("SEARCH CELL ADDRESS"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing And Range("FOUND ROW ADDRESS") <> "NOT FOUND !" Then
        Cells(Range("FOUND ROW ADDRESS").Value, 1).Color = 65535
    End If
End Sub
```